# WordPress REST API - browser gives JSON response without authentication

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, oauth

I am using WP REST API and oAuth1.0 server plugin for authentication. So far Postman required to be authentcated to access endpoint, but browser needs no authentication. Anyone can access the API response through the browser. Is it possible to restrict the API access in browser? I do not want unauthenticated people to see sensitive data of API.

P.S. oAuth1.0 server plugin is activated and authentication in Postman works perfectly!

Example. When I enter `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/categories` in browser I get JSON response of categories and when I enter same endpoint in Postman I get:

```
{
  "code": "json_oauth1_missing_parameter",
  "message": "Missing OAuth parameter oauth_token",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a whole day of searching I finally came to a two possible solutions. Both worked for me fine (personally chose first one).

```
add_filter('rest_pre_dispatch', function($result){
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return new WP_Error('rest_requires_authentication', __('Authentication is required for this action.'), array('status' => 403));
    }
});
```

Or

```
add_filter('rest_authentication_errors', function($result) {
    if (!empty($result)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return new WP_Error('restx_logged_out', 'Sorry, you must be logged in to make a request.', array('status' => 401));
    }
    return $result;
});
```

It is sad that WP REST API plugin is not handling this itself.